# Passing a variable in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables

I currently have this page in my Android App:

[image]

I am wanting to pass the data added into these fields to a .txt file stored on the device.

Code below:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/Button02"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/btn2" />
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView android:text="Please insert details below to confirm you have completed and understood the app" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Forename" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Surname" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="Staff ID" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonformdata"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I believe this is called FileWriter? And I have created a .java file in my project called 'FileWriterExample.java'. What I am struggling on doing is being able to pass the data between my XML file 'Screen10.xml' and this 'FileWriterExample' java file.

In my FileWriterExample file I have the following code:

```
package org.example.screens;

import  java.io.File; 
import  java.io.FileWriter; 
import  java.io.IOException;

public class  FileWriterExample  { 

  FileWriter writer; 
  File file;

  public  void  write () { 
    // Create File 
     file =  new  File ( "FileWriterTest.txt" ) ; 
     try  { 
       // new FileWriter (file, true) - if the file already exists 
       // the bytes are written to the end of the file 

       // new FileWriter (file) - if the file already exists 
       // this will overwrite 
       writer =  new  FileWriter ( file, true ) ; 

       // text is written to the stream 
    writer.write (edittext1 +" ") ; 

       // text is written to the stream 
    writer.write (edittext2 +" ") ;

       // text is written to the stream 
    writer.write (edittext3 +" ") ;

       // Write the stream to the file 
       // Should always be run at the end, so that the stream  
       // is empty and everything in the file . stands 
       writer.flush () ; 

       // Closes the stream 
       writer.close () ; 
    }  catch  ( Exception e ) { 
      e.printStackTrace () ; 
    } 
  }

  public static  void  main ( String []  args ) { 
    FileWriterExample fileWriterExample =  new  FileWriterExample () ; 
    fileWriterExample.write () ; 
  } 
}
```

Now I'm sure the variable is passed where I have edit text fields? How do I link the variables so that this would work? If the code for my project is needed I can upload it, if this will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the data to be written to the file when the user clicks the submit button. You can do that inside the `onClick()` method of the listener that is attached to this button as follows:

```
try{

FileOutputStream fout = openFileOutput(“yourfile.txt”,MODE_PRIVATE);

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

osw.write(editText1.getText().toString()+" ");
osw.write(editText2.getText().toString()+" ");
osw.write(editText3.getText().toString()+" ");

osw.close();

fout.close();

}catch(Exception e){

//do the exception handling
}
```

If you intend to use your own class that handles all the writing and reading, you may create an instance of the class inside the `onClick()` method and call a read/write method on it with the appropriate parameters.